# Run WP-CLI using PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, docker, wp-cli

I've installed WP-CLI on the Mac and my next step is to execute WP-CLI commands using PHP script.

I've tried to implement it the following way but I do not see anything happening. Can someone please look at my code and tell me that what I'm doing wrong?

```
define( 'WP_CLI_ROOT', '/usr/local/bin/wp' );
include WP_CLI_ROOT . '';
$output = shell_exec("wp --info");
echo "<pre>".$output."</pre>";
```

Do I need to configure and setup wp-cli with my PHP files?

Also, when I type **wp --info** on my terminal the following information comes up. Nothing is appearing beside the **Package Dir** & **global config**. do I also need to make adjustments to wp-cli?

```
MAC-00343:htdocs mike$ wp --info
PHP binary: /usr/bin/php
PHP version:    5.6.30
php.ini used:   
WP-CLI root dir:    phar://wp-cli.phar
WP-CLI vendor dir:  phar://wp-cli.phar/vendor
WP_CLI phar path:   /Users/mike/Docker/xamp/www/wordpress_wwws/htdocs
WP-CLI packages dir:    
WP-CLI global config:   
WP-CLI project config:  
WP-CLI version: 1.3.0
```

Any help or suggestions will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a server like `MAMP` running? Are you working inside a wp directory?

Comment: I'm running WordPress on DOCKER. I'm not using WordPress docker image but have manually installed WP in a directory inside Docker. 

Docker/xamp/www/wordpress_wwws/htdocs

But I'm not working inside the wp directory. I'm trying to execute wp-cli commands via custom PHP script.

p.s: I've also tried my PHP code after installing WP-CLI Docker image. But it didn't work.

Comment: Prehaps you can try to shell-exec “php wp —info” ?

Comment: See also [Running WPCLI in php script · Issue #1924 · wp-cli/wp-cli](https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/issues/1924#issuecomment-268402112)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your wp cli aren't in the **path** environment variable, you should add your **wp cli root** to the path environment as following, hopefully this is helpful. For reference all wp cli command, visit the url - https://wpcommands.com

```
<?php
$saved = getenv("path");    // get the value of PATH environment variable and save current value
$newld = "/usr/local/bin";          // extra paths to add - in this case, it should be your wp cli root
if ($saved)
{
    $newld .= ":$saved";
}
// append old paths if any
putenv("path=$newld");        // set new value

// exec wp cli command
$output = shell_exec("wp --info");
echo "<pre>".$output."</pre>";


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Here is what `wp --info` returns on my terminal.

the only main difference I see is the `php.isi used:` field.

Sorry I cant help more, but I dont know what DOCKER is, and I am using MAMP, not XAMP

`phar path` is just the current directory I'm working in

Comment: Thanks for your help. But what about my PHP code? Is this the right way to execute wp-cli commands from a PHP script? e.g. I've also tried stuff suggested here but saw nothing in the output:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37294485/using-wp-cli-through-php

Comment: kind of taking a guess here, but, if `wp --info` returns an array - the `echo` function would experience and `array -> string` conversion error, have you tried `var_dump` - please note this is speculation based on the accepted answer here https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/219230/utilize-wp-cli-from-inside-wordpress-not-ssh  -- `echo implode(PHP_EOL, $retval) . PHP_EOL;`

Comment: Yeah, I've tried var_dump and a number of other things. var_dump returns NULL. Thanks for your help :)